How to access R variables in Spark SQL
I have several R variables created in an %r cell in my notebook file in Azure Databricks. I want to access that variable to use in my where clause in a query in a %sql cell in the same notebook.
It is my understanding that the following solution should ideally work. Here is a toy example of what I am trying to achieve. I have the following variables defined in my R cell:
%r
dt_1 <- 20230101
dt_2 <- 20230131

I believe I should be able to use the sparkR.conf() function to achieve what I am attempting. This is what I have tried:
%r
sparkR.conf("db.dt1", dt_1)
sparkR.conf("db.dt2", dt_2)

It is my understanding that I should now be able to reference these variables in a %sql cell using the names defined above such that the following queries should return the same results:
%sql
select *
from tbl
where date between '${db.dt1}' and '{$db.dt2}'

and
%sql
select *
from tbl
where date between 20230101 and 20230131

However, when I run the first query no results are returned, whereas the second query returns the results I expect. Any ideas as to why this issue may be occurring would be greatly appreciated. I am also open to alternate approaches.

Use of Databricks widgets is suggested

Is there a way to use a variable already defined in R as the default for the widget values rather than having to hard code it?

EDIT: I have achieved a working solution using databricks widgets. Thank you to @vivekatal for the suggestion
For a more specific solution, I used databricks text widgets:
dbutils.widgets.text(name = "date_1", default_value = dt_1)
dbutils.widgets.text(name = "date_2", default_value = dt_2)

I was then able to call these values in my sql query by referencing them with ${date_1} and ${date_2} in my query

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
